# How can I add spell checking ability in Google Talk?

Tags: spell-check, google-talk

Is there any way to add spell checking ability to Google Talk?

Comment: Would an alternate client be an acceptable option? Pidgin supports spellcheck, but of course, not voice.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek An alternative client that support Voice (or Video) is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [tinySpell](http://tinyspell.numerit.com/#features). It allows you to use spell-checking system-wide:

[image]

[PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) has [similar capabilities](http://www.phraseexpress.com/spelling-correction.htm):

[image]

Comment: For those looking to choose between the two, the clues seem to be in the names. tinySpell is a small program concentrating on spelling, PhraseExpress is a large program with many features and settings concentrating on phrases. Both programs can be disabled by default and enabled for particular programs, or vice versa.